# How to fix: double free or corruption (out) Aborted (core dumped) in C++

Tags: c++, gcc, command-line, g++

I've recently been working on a C++ project of mine, and I ran into a problem with the executable:

```
    std::string commanddata;
    std::string input;
    std::string cmdname;
    int commandlength = 0;
    if (commandlength == 0){}else{} // This is so that G++ doesn't complain that I have got a variable and never used it (I'm compiling at -Werror)
    while (true)
    {        
        input = DS_IO.kscanf(">>>"); // This is a specific function to get input from the user
        // Record the command length
        int commandlength = sizeof(input);

        // Make sure that the user doesn't just send us nothing
        if (commandlength <= 0)
            {
                continue;
            }
            else
            {
                // Get the first word from the command
            std::stringstream sstream(input);
            sstream >> cmdname;
            // Loops through the input string to remove everything up to and including a space delimiter
            for (int i = 0; i <= commandlength; i++)
            {
                if (input[i] == 32)
                {
                    commanddata = input;
                    commanddata.erase(input.begin(), input.begin() + i);
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    continue;
                }
            }
            // print out the data to make sure it's all working
            std::cout << "What you entered: " << input << std::endl;
            std::cout << "The command name: " << cmdname << std::endl;
            std::cout << "The command metadata: " << commanddata << std::endl;
        }
    }
```

The code works fine, but my problem is as soon as it reaches the end of the loop, it freaks out and gives this error:

**EXPECTED BEHAVIOUR:**

```
chemeriov@mikumputer:~/dev/DigitalSledgehammer$ ./a.out
>>>echo Hello world
What you entered: Hello world
The command name: echo
The command metadata: Hello world
>>>
```

**EXPERIENCED BEHAVIOUR:**

```
chemeriov@mikumputer:~/dev/DigitalSledgehammer$ ./a.out
>>>echo Hello world
What you entered:  Hello world
The command name: echo
The command metadata:  Hello world

double free or corruption (out)
Aborted (core dumped)
chemeriov@mikumputer:~/dev/DigitalSledgehammer$
```

How to fix this?

Comment: *"This is so that G++ doesn't complain that I have got a variable and never used it"* If you're a beginner, GCC probably knows better than you. :P In this case you've got two variables with the same name, one of them unused.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Yeah, G++ probably is better at this than I am XD Where is the duplicate variable? I can't see another commandlength variable anywhere... *EDIT*:, No I see it now :) But, when I change it, I just get a **Segmentation fault (core dumped)**

Comment: That crash is probably for some other reason...

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, yeah. I'm not sure what it was, but it's probably something to do with the `input.begin() + i` overlap that @Soonts mentioned

Comment: @Nex -- Don't tag `C` if the code is C++.

Comment: Run your code in a debugger or try `valgrind`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks very much to @Soonts, who fixed my problem!

**Another issue, `commanddata.erase( input.begin()` is obviously wrong, a container can’t erase ranges inside other unrelated containers. A correct usage is `something.erase(something.begin(), ..`**

You can clearly tell I'm a noob at this :)

Answer (score 0):

The `sizeof(input)` is a constant number, like 16 bytes. To find length of the string, call `input.length()` method.

Comment: Thanks for such a quick reply! I'm afraid it didn't work though, I'm still getting the error...

Comment: @Nex Another issue, `commanddata.erase` reduces length of the string, so the next time it runs the `input.begin() + i` iterator points well past the end of the string.

Comment: Another issue, `commanddata.erase( input.begin()` is obviously wrong, a container can’t erase ranges inside other unrelated containers. A correct usage is `something.erase(something.begin(), ..`

Comment: It's a shame this is a comment, not a reply, or I would set this as the solution :) (That might sound a bit noobish, but this is my first stackoverflow post XD)